# Incompatible association

Tags: current-source, voltage-source, operational-amplifier

I know that operational amplifiers have a stage in which there is an incompatible association (VCCS + VCVS). How do I show that this configuration gives an infinite gain? I am considering general two port networks - ideally, I'd get this configuration, but I can't see how to show mathematically that the gain is infinite.
[image]

(EDIT)The original circuit I am solving is this one:
[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're talking about. It looks like you have a very specific mental model of an opamp in mind, but if you can claim you have a theoretically perfect VCVS, you can just as well say you have a theoretically perfect opamp. Pretty much the same thing.

Comment: You take Ohm's law: V = I * R The current from the VCCS is I, the input impedance of the VCVC is R now what will V be? Assuming I is not zero.